# Incredimail emails won't scroll

Tags: email

The Incredimail email program seems to have an on-going problem in that emails in preview and main viewing do not scroll on some installations.Has anyone found a cure?

Answer (score 0):

Highlight and while email is Highlighted move mouse pointer down to see all the email

Comment: a GIF would be useful

Comment: Will try that out. have left Partner on Incredimail and I've moved to Thunderbird. Far less frustrating.